# Query to replace specific date range in a column

Tags: sql-update

I have a table that houses information uploaded from a template (via another application).  Well i noticed that the year was wrong (code in the application issue) and caused about 3000 lines of incorrect dates. My question is, how would i write a query to replace all the 20150101 (incorrect date) with 20160101 (correct date)?  I am pretty sure its the UPDATE routine but i am not a SQL programmer so i am a tad lost.  I am using latest SSMS.

Table: TRANS_USER_FORECAST_EDITS_FROM_EXCEL
Column Name: mo_day_year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DO A SELECT FIRST TO SEE HOW MANY RECORD YOU NEED TO UPDATE..

SELECT * FROM TRANS_USER_FORECAST_EDITS_FROM_EXCEL 
WHERE mo_day_year = '20150101'

THEN COPY YOUR RESULT AND RUN THE QUERY BELOW TO UPDATE ALL THE RECORDS.

BEGIN TRAN 
UPDATE TRANS_USER_FORECAST_EDITS_FROM_EXCEL SET mo_day_year = '20160101' 
WHERE mo_day_year = '20150101' 
COMMIT

Comment: I identified 2000 rows that need this update.  Oh, i forgot one HUGELY IMPORTANT THING.  I have to do this within a certain TRANS_DATE (date we uploaded it) or i might overwrite other data lol.  So i need to tack this on to the end of your code?  *** AND CAST(TRANS_DATE AS DATE) between '12/1/2014' and '12/31/2014'  ***

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, it's indeed an `update` statement:

```
UPDATE TRANS_USER_FORECAST_EDITS_FROM_EXCEL
SET    mo_day_year = 20150101
WHERE  mo_day_year = 20160101
```